# Doctrine ORM error :  Unknown column type varchar requested

Tags: doctrine-orm

Ok, so i just assigned a new project which uses Doctrine and Zend. This is my first time using Doctrine, and i came upon an error for which google didn't came up with any answer.
I added a new field (VARCHAR 17) to a table, added getter/setter functions in the Entity for that table, then ran orm:generate-proxies.

All good, except now i am getting this error when trying to save anything: Unknown column type varchar requested.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that doctrine annotation doesn't know about the underlying database. So what you have to do is mark your field as type string with length of 17 in your case:

```
/**
* mySuperField
* \ORM\Column(name="mySuperField", type="string", length=17)
*/
$mySuperField;
```

For reference about how to map entity properties see also [Doctrine Basic Mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html)

Answer (score -1):

At first learn about doctrine commands
orm:generate-entities to write getter/setter functions in the Entity files,
orm:schema-tool:update to update db tables,
you should not do this work manually, just write yaml/xml/php schema and run them.

If you use [Bisna library](https://github.com/guilhermeblanco/ZendFramework1-Doctrine2) to integrate doctrine2 with zf, there must be "adapterClass" and "mappingDirs[]" options in application.ini file to describe where schema files are.

Use type "string" instead of varchar in entity and schema files.
I prefer yaml schemas:

```
username:
  type: string
  length: 17
```